# Redirecting certain events to different members of a stackpane

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, mouseevent, openstreetmap

I have a JavaFX StackPane with two members. The bottom member is a webview of openstreetmap using [this library](https://github.com/sothawo/mapjfx). The top member is a canvas where im able to draw on the map. The canvas handles some events like scrolling or dragging, to display the desired part and notifies the map to fit the canvas.

Now i want to use a functionality implemented on the bottom layer. With a mouseClick, the webview is able to call an java event handler that gives me latitude and longitude for the point clicked. Sadly i cant access this functionality from the other layer, because the information seem to originate from the [javascript code](https://github.com/sothawo/mapjfx/blob/main/src/main/resources/mapview.js#L94) that is used in the webview.

How do i redirect only the onMouseClicked event to the bottom layer, while keeping the rest of the events on the top layer. Like somehow write code that simulates a mouseclick on the bottom layer on the same position as the mouseclick on the top layer.

Sadly solutions like pickOnBounds() and setMouseTransparent() does not work like that, because it should work regardless of the click position and still block dragging and scrolling from reaching the bottom layer.

I have one solution. I could calculate the latitude and longitude with my canvas. But im hesitant to do this, because i want the more precise data my webview in putting out (Sadly the earth isnt flat and that makes translating a 2d plane to accurate coordinates pretty hard, it works but it gets pretty sketchy at the edges of my canvas).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Read up on [handling events](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm) (specifically the sections on processing, filters and handlers).